# NotificationManager: notify: id corrupted: sent , got back 0

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm facing a issue with NotificationManager in my app for the past couple of days and I don't seem to be getting closer to solving it.

I have a very simple ThreadPoolExecutor to download multiple files. but same time i need to show download progress inside notification bar.

```
class DownloadTask implements Runnable{
String url;
String localFile;
DownloadResultUpdateTask resultUpdateTask;
Context mContext;
final int mNotificationId;

NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

public DownloadTask(String urlIn, String localFileIn,
                    DownloadResultUpdateTask drUpdateTask,Context context,int notificationId){
    url = urlIn;
    localFile = localFileIn;
    resultUpdateTask = drUpdateTask;
    mContext = context;
    mNotificationId = notificationId;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String msg;
    if(downloadFile(mNotificationId)){
        msg = "file downloaded successful "+url;


    }else{
        msg = "failed to download the file "+url;
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Download Failed");
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    //update results download status on the main thread
    resultUpdateTask.setBackgroundMsg(msg);
    DownloadManager.getDownloadManager().getMainThreadExecutor()
            .execute(resultUpdateTask);
}

public boolean downloadFile(int  notifId){
    try{
        //pending intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(localFile));
            intent.setData(apkUri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(localFile)));
        }
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        //createing notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Set notification information:
        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Downloading PDF")
                .setContentText("0%")
                .setProgress(100, 0, false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .build();

        //Send the notification:
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, notification);

        //downloading file
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        InputStream in = response.body().byteStream();
        FileOutputStream fileOutput =
                new FileOutputStream(localFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*4];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        int target = (int) response.body().contentLength();
        long downloaded = 0;
        int currentPercentage = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            downloaded += bufferLength;
            currentPercentage = (int)(downloaded * 100) / target;
            if (currentPercentage >= 30 && currentPercentage <= 40 || currentPercentage >= 60 && currentPercentage <= 70
                    || currentPercentage >= 90 && currentPercentage <= 100) {
                notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, currentPercentage, false).setContentText(currentPercentage + "%");
                notificationManager.notify(notifId, notificationBuilder.build()); // facing problem in thisl ine
            }
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.close();
        response.body().close();
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Download Completed");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Click to open " +  url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notificationBuilder.build());

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); return false;}
    return true;
}
```

i am able to download all the files successfully. but while updating progress bar 
am keep getting below warning, so that notification get stuck, does not show downloaded successful even it is downloaded. although every time i am passing unique notification id for different downloading notification.

```
W/NotificationManager: notify: id corrupted: sent 519, got back 0
```

i have added  if condition to update progress only when it reaches 40, 60 or in between 90 to 100 just to minimize number of progress update call to increase the performance.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!